# NDK Error when build

Tags: android, android-ndk, native

I'm new to NDK Android. When I edit my .cpp file and run it, I get the following error:

```
Error:unable to rename temporary 'C:\Users\1414\AppData\Local\Temp\native-lib-1ee473.s-465eb1fd' to output file 'C:\Users\1414\AppData\Local\Temp\native-lib-1ee473.s': 'Permission denied'
```

I tried restarting my computer which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

I've also tried invalidating my cache and retsrating but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you can try following steps

1. Delete `*.so` file in libs folder
2. run `ndk-build clean`
3. run `ndk-build`

Comment: which libs folder? libs on project? I cannot find any .so file in my project

Comment: Inside folder name Main , there will be jnilibs or libs folder where the  *.so files are created if NDK is configured and build successfully. Uncertainty  not created for you means NDK not yet successfully build.  Try to re configure NDK.